# Regular expression to match a URL with 6 or more levels

Tags: java, regex, nutch

I am trying to match a URL with 6 or more than 6 levels or sub-paths

```
http://www.domain.com/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6/level7/level8/level9/level10/level11/level12.html
```

I came up with an expression

```
^http:\/\/([a-zA-Z\.-]*)\W(\b\w+\b)
```

...which matches level1 ([demo](http://rubular.com/r/JzIJjD7OUP))

However, when I am trying to match a URL with six or more levels it doesn't seem to work.

```
^http:\/\/([a-zA-Z\.-]*)\W(\b\w+\b){6,}
```

([demo](http://rubular.com/r/ZFWSGXP23j))

Comment: which language?do you want all the levels individually or do you only want to **check** if the url contains more than 6 levels

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I want to check if the url contains more than 6 levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
^http://([a-zA-Z.-]+)/(?:[^/]+/){6,}.*$
```

This matches six or more levels, which is what you said you wanted in the question.  However in the question's title you phrased it "more than six".  If that's what you really want, change the quantifier from `{6,}` to `{7,}`.

On a side note, the forward slash (`/`) has no special meaning in regexes, and doesn't need to be escaped.  Rubular forces you to escape the slash because that's what it uses as the regex delimiter.  Nutch uses Java's built-in regexes, so you should use a tester that the same flavor, like [this one](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Alan. My question was confusing and so I edited my title per your suggestion. Also, thanks for the note on forward slash. I did not realize about rubular uses forward slash as regex delimiter. Yes, my intention behind knowing the right regular expression is to filter urls with 6 or more levels in my regex-urlfilter file in nutch crawl.

Comment: the expression you provided doesn't match the url 'http://www.domain.com/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6/level7/level8/level9/level10/level11/level12.html' though it has 6 & above levels

Comment: I know it doesn't consume the whole URL, is that what you mean?  I was thinking in terms of `grep`, which always returns the whole line where the match occurs (by default, anyway).  But now I think about it, the software probably expects the regex to match the whole URL.  I'll update the answer and tack a `.*$` onto the regex.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I suppose thats how regex-urlfilter in nutch would match/filter urls. I am a beginner in using nutch and regular exp

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
^http:\/\/([a-zA-Z\.-]*)(\/[\w\.]+){6,}
```

http://rubular.com/r/QZlidUqheq