# regex to match any url that is 1 level deep

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

1. to match a URL that is 1 level deep
2. and a url (x)levels deep but under a specific directory

How do I achieve this in regex?

I saw a regex solution from this question : [Regular expression to match a URL with 6 or more levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505406)

But, I am unable to generate a working one for my 2 conditions above.

Comment: do you mean "or" instead of "and", because a url is either 1 level deep *or* x levels deep - it can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^someserver.com/(\w+|specific(/\w+){n})$
```

Where `n` is `x-1` from your question

---

If you need separate regex:

For one level:

```
^someserver.com/\w+$
```

For x levels under specific:

```
^someserver.com/specific(/\w+){x-1}$
```

Comment: This doesn't allow dots in the path! I mean the "for one level" one at least.

Comment: @ehsun7b dots in paths are poor design - I’ve never seen one. If you really want to go there, use `[\w.]` instead of `\w`

Comment: But they are valid, and nowadays they are very common in API versioning. `/api/1.0/something`

Comment: or a username might contain dot and then API to get the user's details by username might look like `/users/{username}` which for that user might be `/users/some.username`

Comment: @ehsun7b But the “/api/1.0/“ would be part of the “specific” root; you wouldn’t typically find dots in the path to a resource relative to some root

Comment: There are lots of user-cases, as I said in my first comment I am referring to the "For one level", imaging a key-value pair API where the get API is `/{key}` and basically key can be any kind of string

Comment: @ehsun7b Better use `[^/]` instead of `\w` then

Comment: As long as the character, here dot is valid to be in a URL, the regex pattern should allow it. I do remember 20 years ago people were using regex patterns for validating emails that did not allow dot, until Gmail pops up and encourages dot in the email address. I do remember people were using regex patterns that did not allow domain names with top level domain longer than 3 and now all those patterns are wrong with new domains of `.sfotware` and ...

Comment: anyway I suggest `"^/[^/]+/?$"` for one level

Answer (score -1):

what if you just split it..?

```
string url = "stackoverflow.com/questions";

if (url.Split('/').Length == 2) //check for one level
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("One Level");
}

if (url.Split('/')[0].ToLower() == "stackoverflow.com") //check for base
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Good base");
}
```

may need to handle http:// though